# Which LDAP attribute is modified when User account gets locked?

Tags: ldap

When a user account gets locked in an LDAP server which LDAP standard attribute is being modified? Is that standard LDAP one or specific to the server (i.e. Active Director/ Novell etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very old [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-vchu-ldap-pwd-policy-00) , but I do not think any work has been done on this in some time. Also, Sun and UnboundID directory server support the [Account Usable](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/status-of-user-accounts-in-a-directory-server-database/) request and response controls.

Answer (score 0):

Check the User-Account-Control Attribute, described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this attribute is Active Directory specific. Am I correct? Is there something more generic that would apply to all LDAP servers?

Comment: I dont think this is AD specific, check http://www.tools4ever.com/products/user-management-resource-administrator/documents/managing-ldap-directory-services/328/

Answer (score 0):

The draft Terry Gardner referred to is mostly implemented in OpenLDAP, so if that's what you're using that covers it. Specifically the attribute is pwdLockedTime. It is either absent or set to the time the account was locked. It is an operational attribute so you have to request it specifically or via "+".

Comment: I am using Novell as the LDAP server.